# Unit and integration testing in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing

I'm going to write a quite large application for school project in C++. So far I'm quite used to TDD in Java and Ruby using JUnit and RSpec.

But as far as my experience goes, I've never seen any C/C++ project with any test suite.

**What library do you recommend for testing in C++?**
**Are there any good mocking/stubbing frameworks for C++?**

Actually I'm using NetBeans IDE and there seems to be no support for testing whatsoever.
**What tool would you recommend for TDD in C++?**

Is TDD even possible with C++? The compile time seems to me like a big drawback.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439172/testing-code-in-c-c (and others)

Answer (score 7):

The [Boost Test Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) gives you unit tests etc.

Answer (score 6):

We use [Google Test Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). And we don't run tests on every compile on the developers machines. This is a job for a build server.

Comment: Why don't you run tests on every build?

Comment: @Tolli It depends on who makes a build. If it is a human - no tests are run because we want the fastest possible build time. If it is a build server - the tests are always executed.

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of unit test frameworks for C++.  The 2 I have the most experience with are CppUnit and CxxTest.  I prefer CxxTest as I find it easier not to have to register my test cases explicitly as you have to do with CppUnit.  there's an eclipse plugin for CxxTest but I don't know if there's one for NetBeans.  Compile time shouldn't really be an issue with well written C++ and definately isn't a reason to skip unit tests / tdd.

For acceptance testing I've used exactor. This is a java based tool, but it's not difficult to use in a C++ environment.

Answer (score 5):

Comparing CppTest and CppUnit I would go with CppTest. CppTest has less hidden framework and IMO easier to understand and implement. I personally like to see the *main* entry point. I have also included Boost Unit Testing Framework. It is not [xUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) based. I am not a fan, but if you are already using the Boost Library it would be nice to incorporate.

---

**CppTest vs CppUnit**

> •**Ease of creating a unit test and test
>   suite**. Both CppUnit and CppTest create
>   unit tests of class methods, with the
>   class itself derived from some
>   tool-provided Test class. The syntax
>   for CppTest is slightly simpler,
>   though, with the test registration
>   happening inside the class
>   constructor. In the case of CppUnit,
>   the additional macros
>   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE and
>   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_ENDS are needed.
>
> •**Running the tests**. CppTest simply
>   calls the run method on the test
>   suite, while CppUnit uses a separate
>   TestRunner class whose run method is
>   invoked for running the tests.
>
> •**Extending the testing hierarchy**. In
>   the case of CppTest, it is always
>   possible to extend the previous test
>   suite by creating a new class that
>   inherits from the old one. The new
>   class will define some additional
>   functions that add to the unit test
>   pool. You simply invoke the run method
>   on the object of the new class type.
>   CppUnit, in contrast, requires that
>   you use the macro
>   CPPUNIT_TEST_SUB_SUITE along with
>   class inheritance to achieve the same
>   effect.
>
> •**Generating formatted output**. Both
>   CppTest and CppUnit have the ability
>   to customize the output. However,
>   although CppTest has a useful,
>   predefined HTML output formatter,
>   CppUnit does not. However, CppUnit
>   exclusively supports XML formatting.
>   Both support text and compiler style
>   formats.
>
> •**Creating test fixtures**. To use test
>   fixtures, CppUnit requires that the
>   test class be derived from
>   CppUnit::TestFixture. You must provide
>   definitions for the setup and
>   tear-down routines. In the case of
>   CppTest, you need to provide
>   definitions only for the setup and
>   tear-down routines. This is definitely
>   a better solution, as it keeps the
>   client code simple.   •Predefined
>   utility macro support. Both CppTest
>   and CppUnit have a comparable set of
>   macros for asserts, handling floats,
>   and so on.
>
> •**Header files**. CppTest requires that
>   you include a single header file,
>   while CppUnit client code must include
>   multiple headers, like HelperMacros.h
>   and TextTestRunner.h, depending on the
>   features used.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools3_ccptest/index.html?ca=drs-

---

**CPPTEST**

```
#include “cppTest.h”

class myTestWithFixtures : public Test::Suite { 
  void function1_to_test_some_code( );
  void function2_to_test_some_code( );

  public: 
  myTestWithFixtures ( ) { 
      TEST_ADD (function1_to_test_some_code) {...}; 
      TEST_ADD (function2_to_test_some_code) {...}; 
  } 

  protected: 
    virtual void setup( ) { ... };
    virtual void tear_down( ) { ... };
}; 

int main ( ) 
{ 
  myTestWithFixtures tests; 
  Test::TextOutput output(Test::TextOutput::Verbose);
  return tests.run(output);
}
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools3_ccptest/index.html?ca=drs-

---

**CPPUNIT**

```
#include <cppunit/extensions/TestFactoryRegistry.h>
#include <cppunit/ui/text/TextTestRunner.h>
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>

class mystringTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture {
public:
  void setUp() { ... };
  void tearDown() { ... };

  void function1_to_test_some_code() { ... };
  void function2_to_test_some_code() { ... };

  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( mystringTest );
  CPPUNIT_TEST( function1_to_test_some_code );
  CPPUNIT_TEST( function2_to_test_some_code );
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION( mystringTest );
```

with out macros

```
int main ()
{
  CppUnit::TestSuite* suite = new CppUnit::TestSuite("mystringTest");
  suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<mystringTest>("checkLength",
                &mystringTest::checkLength));
  suite->addTest(new CppUnit::TestCaller<mystringTest>("checkValue",
                &mystringTest::checkLength));

  // client code follows next 
  CppUnit::TextTestRunner runner;
  runner.addTest(suite);

  runner.run();
  return 0;
}
```

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ctools2_cppunit/

---

**Boost Unit Testing Framework**

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct CMyFooTestFixture
{
    CMyFooTestFixture() { ... } //SetUp
    ~CMyFooTestFixture() { ... } //TearDown

    void function1_to_test_some_code(CMyFoo& foo) { ... };
    void function2_to_test_some_code(CMyFoo& foo) { ... };
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(MyFooTest, CMyFooTestFixture);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(function1_to_test_some_code)
{
    CMyFoo foo;
    function1_to_test_some_code(foo);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(function1_to_test_some_code2)
{
    CMyFoo foo;
    function1_to_test_some_code(foo);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

http://www.beroux.com/english/articles/boost_unit_testing/

Answer (score 3):

For Integrated Testing, might I suggest the C++ implementation of FIT (Framework for Integrated Test) - http://fit.c2.com aka CEEFIT (http://ceefit.woldrich.com/?page=Home) (at the time of writing this article the ceefit site was down. hopefully it will come back up soon). I have personally used CEEFIT to run Integrated Tests on legacy C++ code-bases that interact with Computer-Aided Design platform API (SolidWorks if you are aware of it). I am fortunate that CEEFIT is open source, because I had to extend it to do custom things, like read multiple tables as input (default behavior is to read a single table for a test-class). After having worked with CEEFIT for at least a year now, I am relatively confident I can run Integrated Tests on most systems with this tool.

Shameless plug - some of my blog posts recounting my experience with CEEFIT with downloads
http://ossandcad.blogspot.com/2009/07/swx-batch-mode-integrated-tests-with.html
http://ossandcad.blogspot.com/2009/02/writing-ceefit-class-like-regular-c.html

There are a few caveats with CEEFIT though - providing input through a table format is not always feasible (not CEEFIT's fault, thats by design of FIT, which CEEFIT simply implements). The source code has not been updated for many years, if memory serves right (since site is down), since 2005 (but since its open source, this has not caused many problems for me in my work).

Answer (score 2):

If you used to use JUnit and jMock, I would like to recommend you :

- [google test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and
- [google mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/).

**Googlemock** and seamless coorperate with **Googletest**.

For TDD, my self use

- [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) and
- [scons](http://www.scons.org/)

with some scripts composed by myself. And all of these work well.

Comment: google test works well but it breaks the intellisense in the netbeans IDE

Answer (score 2):

We are working hard to make unit testing and TDD feasible for C++. We extend Eclipse CDT to do so. Currently you can try:

http://cute-test.com - our unit testing framework with Eclipse CDT plug-in

One of my masters students is currently implementing "Mockator" a mock-object infrastructure that works through dependency injection via introducing template parameters instead of the obligation through inheritance (as for example with google mock). This should become available through our CUTE plug-in later this summer.

Another student team has implemented TDD support for Eclipse CDT, that again will be integrated in our cute plug-in (but will work also without the CUTE framework).

All that will be available for free.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: Have a look at [cfix](http://www.cfix-testing.org/) and [Visual Assert](http://www.visualassert.com/).

Answer (score 0):

unittest++

Answer (score 0):

As you have worked on JUnit , It would be easy for you to work on CPPUnit