# Integration Testing Approach for Code C/C++

Tags: c, integration-testing, googletest

I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439172/testing-code-in-c-c) about Unit Testing for C/C++. I have heard that gtest can be used for Integration Testing. What is the best approach to do Integration Tests? I am afraid that this could replicate Unit/System tests so I am not sure what test technique should I use for C embedded systems.

Comment: Q: Why are you worried "this could replicate Unit/System tests"?  Isn't the only relevant question: "Would these tests be useful?"

Comment: I am trying to do Integration to catch the bugs that does not appear in system nor unit tests. My first thought was to exercise sub systems and then verify the outputs, but I am afraid there is a gap between what the code generates and what the system displays. I just want to follow a solid guideline.

Comment: Here is a really good article comparing Unit testing, Integration testing, End-to-End testing ... and what is (or isn't) actually of "real value" to the end user: [Just Say No to More End-to-End Tests](https://testing.googleblog.com/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html).  To answer your original question: "Yes, Google tests are definitely a form of unit testing."  But read the article ... and use whatever tools you think will help.  Good luck!